# Reading characters array from a text file and convert it to an integer parameter

Tags: fortran, type-conversion, fortran90

I have a large text file like this:

```
!species     #Oxygen
  ind_CO      1.0
  ind_CO2     2.0
  ind_CH4     0.0
  ind_O3      3.0
```

but in my code the characters (ind_CO, ind_CO2, etc) are declared like this:

```
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ind_CO2 = 1 
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ind_CH4 = 2
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ind_O3  = 3
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ind_CO  = 4
```

And the concentration of each species is calculated as C(ind_). So I want
to calculate the product of C(ind_)*(#Oxygen) for each one. That is, I would like to relate the data of text file  and those of code. I tried something like this:

```
program
  implicit none
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ind_CO2 = 1 
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ind_CH4 = 2
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ind_O3  = 3
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ind_CO  = 4

  REAL      :: C(4)        ! Concentration for each Compound
  REAL      :: numO        ! Number of Oxygens
  REAL      :: ANS(4)      ! To Calculate
  INTEGER   :: err
  CHARACTER :: species*11

  open (unit=15, file="data.txt", status='old',access='sequential', form='formatted', action='read' )
  err=0
  do
      read (15, *,IOSTAT=err)  species, numO
      if (err==-1) exit
  ! I don 't know if it is possible to convert a character to an integer   
  ! parameter in such a way that the index of the matrix corresponds to
  ! the right compound 
      ANS(species) = C(species)*numO
      write (*, *)  species, numO, ANS(species)
  enddo
  close(15)
  end program
```

I know it is not correct, but my idea is to insert at the matrix C the name that is saved for each compound at the beginning of the code.
So I would like to ask you if it is possible to read or convert these characters and relate them to the declared parameters.

Comment: I have to do it on fortran90

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions to get more attention.

Comment: Why did you add [tag:fortran77]? You said you need Fortran 90, didn't you?

Comment: And read about Fortran **namelists**, it may be useful for you.

Comment: Yes, I have to do it on f90. But any idea from the previous version could be useful, I hope so.
I will check for namelists,
Thank you

Comment: In that case don't add the previous version tag. People can answer with older version code anyway, it is valid even in Fortran 90.

Comment: Actually, the namelists will not be that useful here, they would require quite a substantial restructuring of both of the code and of the data file.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I was trying to find a quick way because my code is a little time consuming. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fortran there is no intrinsic way to map symbol names to character strings.  The simplest approach here is to simply store your species names as a character array and use a loop to find the matching name for the string you read from the file.

```
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  integer, parameter :: nspecies=4
  character(len=11),dimension(nspecies) :: species= &
      ['ind_CO2','ind_CH4','ind_O3','ind_CO']                                                                  
  character(len=11) :: input                                                                                                                                
  input='ind_CH4' ! from file                                                                                                                               
  do  i = 1,nspecies                                                                                                                                        
     if ( input .eq. species(i) )exit                                                                                                                       
  enddo                                                                                                                                                     
  if ( i.gt.nspecies )then
   write(*,*)'error ',input,' not found'
  else                                                                                                  
   write(*,*)'read input is ',i,trim(species(i))
  endif                                                                                                             
  end
```

Comment: "In fortran there is no intrinsic way to map symbol names to character strings." This is what i was looking for.
My question was a little non-understandable.
Thank you very much for your work and time.